# JSF Submit Form to CommandButton using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/event.xhtml

I want do that same what in showcase but without refreshing page. Like:  setting value in inputtext and click on button to view result, but if i have `<p:ajax event="blur" />`or `<p:ajax/>` then i must click two times on the button

```
 <p:inputText id="data" value="#{buttonView.data}">
   <p:ajax/>
 </p:inputText>


<p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" id="ajax"  actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" />
```

Maybe something like use outpupanel and update that panel in commandbutton?

Answer (score 0):

If you are to use the `<p:commandButton />` then the form will be submitted. In this case use `update` attribute of `<p:commandButton />` to update the target component.

If you want to update another component as soon as you type then use `<p:ajax event="keyup" update="your_target_component_id" />` to update your target component. (YOur event can be keyup, keypress, change, blur, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you mixing the concept of using `p:ajax` with the functionality of the `p:commandButton`.

> Basically, usage of `p:ajax` is intended to partially process the
>   field(s) value and update the component(s) of the `form` even without
>   submitting it.

**Example:**
You have Countries and States drop-downs (pre-populated) on a screen (let's say registration) with some other fields, but if user changes the country, you need to refill the States drop-down and update on the screen asynchronously. There you need to use the `p:ajax`.

> On the other hand, `p:commandButton` is intended to submit the `form`
>   (not to update the components initially). However, it also supports
>   the updating of the components using `update` attribute.

**Example:**
Now, reconsider the above example with similar drop-downs (but disabled with fixed values). Now you know that your screen has nothing to be updated and you just have to tackle with validation (if any) and submit the form (update if required).

As far as you are concerned with using the `p:ajax` on the `p:inputText` for some asynchronously updates on the screen and `p:commandButton` to finally submit the `form`, that totally depends on your requriement.

Answer (score -2):

Instead p:ajax try f:ajax. You can use < f:ajax event="change" render="@this"/>
once the value gets change, same will reflect in backing bean.

Comment: Totally not related.., should work with PrimeFaces as well. Most likely op has other (unvisible) problems